# Power BI RLS with Azure Active Directory B2B

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory, dax, row-level-security

I would like to try using AAD B2B to address my AD Group on premise and external user data. But I not sure whether can I get the all AAD data through Powerbi datasource (Analysis Service) because I want to apply Role Level Security based on AD data.
Therefore, I would like to know what AD data (e.g. CN, OU, UPN, SamAccountName... ) will be stored in AAD as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The below table lists some of the [common on-prem attributes that are synchronized to Azure AD.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-provisioning/concept-attributes#attributes-and-expressions)

[image]

You can also look at [Azure AD Connect sync: Attributes synchronized to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized#attributes-to-synchronize%C2%A0) for more details.